# Django Send email for new model object create

Tags: django, django-models

I want to send email if user placed a new order. I want to do the send email function from my models.py. Is it possible?? I setup my settings.py for email. I am looking for a easiest way to do this. I don't want to touch my views so is it possible?

#this is my Order model

```
class Order(models.Model):

    PENDING_PAYMENT = 'Pending Payment'
    ON_HOLD = 'On Hold'

    status_choices = [

        ('Cancel', 'Cancel'),
        ('Pending Payment', 'Pending Payment'),
        ('On Hold', 'On Hold'),
        ('Waiting For Payment', 'Waiting For Payment'),
        ('Processing', 'Processing'),
        ('Done', 'Done'),

    ]

    orderstatus_choices = [

        ('Cancel', 'Cancel'),
        ('Pending Payment', 'Pending Payment'),
        ('On Hold', 'On Hold'),
        ('Waiting For Payment', 'Waiting For Payment'),
        ('Processing', 'Processing'),
        ('Done', 'Done'),

    ]

    Ordinary = 'Ordinary'

    customer_choices = [

        ('Ordinary', 'Ordinary'),
        ('Police', 'Police'),
        ('RAB', 'RAB'),
        ('DGIF', 'DGIF'),
        ('CID', 'CID'),
        ('NAVY', 'NAVY'),
        ('Air Force', 'Air Force'),
        ('Army', 'Army'),
        ('DB', 'DB'),
        ('Administration', 'Administration'),

    ]

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    paymentMethod = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    taxPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    shippingPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    totalPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    isPaid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paidAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    isDelivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deliverAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=220, choices=status_choices, default=PENDING_PAYMENT)
    orderStatus= models.CharField(max_length=220, choices=orderstatus_choices, default=ON_HOLD, blank=True, null=True)
    customerType = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, choices=customer_choices, default=Ordinary)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. But you probably shouldn't. It will try to send the email while user is waiting for the request to finish, which will generally make the user wait longer (bad user experience), and it also might happen the mail server connection will timeout, so the user will see an error just because you couldn't send the email at given moment.

Reconsider the approach and try to send the email either via task queue or a cronjob. If you insist on the direct approach, you can put a condition like `if not self.pk` into the `save()` method

```
class Order(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # model does not have primary key, it's a new order then
        if not self.pk:
            self.send_order_email()

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Better (but still not recommended) approach would be to trigger it in your view, since so the email logic wouldn't be bound directly to saving a new Order model, but to a view where the order is finished (these are two different cases even if they look the same, eg. you might create the models in tests and you don't want to mock the email at each case).

sidenote: according to PEP8, the variable names should be using `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` (eg. `is_delivered` instead of `isDelivered`)

Comment: I am able to send mail from my view and I used this.
send_mail(
        'Title',
        'A new order has been placed to your account, Please pay soon'{order._id},
        'laksura.com.bd@gmail.com',
        [user.email],
        fail_silently=False,
    )

but now I want to send the order._id object in my message, How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use Django's signals post_save feature. Using signals, you can send email to your user without touch your views file and you can also access any of your fields say _id in your case.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Order)
def send_email(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    obj_id = instance._id
    # your code to send email
    ...
```

You can read more about django signals in official documentation also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/